# connect to oracle (AIX unix version) from windows using c#

Tags: c#, unix, database-connection, oracle9i

I have an oracle 9i db installed on IBM AIX unix. This server is a remote server.

I can connect it through Putty and SQL DEVELOPER.

**REQUIREMENT**

1) Want to connect to it from my windows application using c#.
2) Cannot install anything on oracle unix.

So, how can i connect using c#?

Please suggest some solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html).

[Samples here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm).

Comment: i have one question.
do i need to install odp.net on my machine or on the oracle server machine (unix)

as i mentioned before i cannot install anything on that machine

Comment: hey i am new to this.. can you please tell me if i am already connecting through SQL DEVELOPER on my pc to my remote oracle server... does that mean some oracle client is already installed on my pc?
and also if i install this client here on my pc,will this trouble my remote server?

Comment: You need an Oracle client to access the database. There are several different clients for various purposes and you need to pick the one you need. For accessing Oracle through .NET code ODP.NET is a suitable option. Installing clients do not affect the server itself.